# To-Do List Not Displaying Added Entries

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get my to-do list working. I've been following a tutorial on YouTube and after writing out all the code, nothing seems to be added/displayed if I attempt to add something to the to-do list. I've had a good look through everything and also rewatched the video and double checked I had the exact same code (the video doesn't provide the source code). I'm lost at this point and would appreciate any help.

The functionality of the project should allow people to add something to the to-do list, edit items they have in their list and also be able to delete their item.

Can anyone spot any obvious issues?

Is there any way to not have the input field display after adding an entry, until the user clicks the "edit" button? When I add an entry, not only does it show what I had entered, it also displayed the input field to edit the entry like so:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

```js
// Add To-Do's
var add_todo_btn = document.getElementById('add-btn');
var todo_input = document.getElementById('todo-input');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
add_todo_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var todo = todo_input.value;

    var item = document.createElement('DIV');
  item.classList.add('item');
  
  var item_text = document.createElement('DIV');
  item_text.classList.add('item-text');
  item_text.textContent = todo;
  
  var edit_input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  edit_input.classList.add('edit-input');
  edit_input.classList.add('hide');
  edit_input.name = 'edit-input';
  edit_input.type = 'text';
  edit_input.value = todo;
  
  var edit_input_btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  edit_input_btn.textContent = 'UPDATE';
  edit_input_btn.classList.add('action-btn');
  edit_input_btn.classList.add('update-btn');
  edit_input_btn.classList.add('hide');
  edit_input_btn.type = 'button';
  
  var action_btns = document.createElement('DIV');
  action_btns.classList.add('action-btns');
  
  var edit_btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  edit_btn.classList.add('action-btn');
  edit_btn.classList.add('edit-btn');
  edit_btn.textContent = 'EDIT';
  
  // Edit To-Do's
  edit_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    edit_input.classList.remove('hide');
    item_text.classList.add('hide');
    edit_input_btn.classList.remove('hide');
    edit_input_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        item_text.textContent = edit_input.value;
      edit_input.classList.add('hide');
      item_text.classList.remove('hide');
      edit_input_btn.classList.add('hide');
    });
  });
  
  var remove_btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  remove_btn.classList.add('action-btn');
  remove_btn.classList.add('remove-btn');
  remove_btn.textContent = 'REMOVE';
  
  // Remove To-Do's
  remove_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  });
  
  action_btns.append(edit_input_btn);
  action_btns.append(edit_btn);
  action_btns.append(remove_btn);
  item.append(item_text);
  item.append(edit_input);
  item.append(action_btns);
  item.append(item);

    todo_input.value = '';  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Todo App</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="header">
       <div class="title">To-Do List</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="todo-input" id="todo-input" class="input-element" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
      <button type="button" name="add-btn" id="add-btn" class="input-btn">
      Add To-Do
      </button>
      <div class="todo-list" id="list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the first error that appears is due to the fact that you are appending item to item, while you should append it to list; replace "item.append(item);" with "list.append(item);"

Comment: ah I see. That has fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to have the input field (for editing the entry) not display unless the user clicks the "edit" button?

Comment: Add a disabled attribute "<button disabled type=..." to your button. Also, set an event yourButton.addEventListener('input', enableFunction); where enableFunction add/remove the disabled attribute